# HBase ORM for Ruby

Tags: ruby, orm, hbase

What HBase ORM/adapters for Ruby exists? Which are the best? WHY?

Comment: Rhino? https://github.com/sqs/rhino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about which one is best, but:

- Rhino
  https://github.com/sqs/rhino
- Bigrecord
  https://github.com/openplaces/bigrecord

My inclination would be to create a Datamapper adapter - you then get the benefit of a powerful ORM (assuming you think that is a benefit) and standard tests. I see someone started a project a few days ago but hasn't yet pushed any code, perhaps watch it on Github?:

- DM-HBase-Adapter https://github.com/hasham2/dm-hbase-adapter

Answer (score 5):

Rhino and Bigrecord seem to be not active for several months.

Here is a more active Ruby ORM for hbase: https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but there's Massive Record, which is actively maintained as of Aug 2011 and is based on ActiveModel.

https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record/